How can I add a new table, populate it with reference data, and add a foreign key constraint to an existing table at the same time?
Using a .sqlproj, I want to do the following:

Add this table:

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ref_newtable] (
    [id]            [dbo].[dtNUMBER] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [pk_ref_newtable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80)
);


Add data to the table:

INSERT INTO dbo.ref_newtable (id)
VALUES (0),
       (1),
       (2)


Add a foreign key constraint to an existing table:

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[existingtable] (
    ... existing stuff ...
    CONSTRAINT [fk_existingtable_newtable] FOREIGN KEY ([newly_constrained_column])
      REFERENCES [dbo].[ref_newtable] ([id])
);

The newly_constrained_column's existing values are all 0, so there should not be an issue with adding the foreign key constraint.
However, when executing the generated script, we see the following error:

The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_existingtable_newtable".

This is happening because the updates to both tables (steps 1 and 3) are occurring before step 2. Is there a way to redefine the order, or otherwise modify the project to get the desired outcome?
I am aware of this question, but the script generated in our case does NOT include NOCHECK on the new FK constraint. Is there a setting for that or something?

You created and populated ref_newtable, but are creating an FK reference from license_client to newtable (not ref_newtable). Might that be the problem? Further confusing things, the error message references constraint fk_LicClnt_RefAppCreStatus and you mention "tables 1 and 3". We need some consistency here, if you want us to help.

It is documented here that new constraints will always be added with NOCHECK https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacdeployoptions.scriptnewconstraintvalidation?view=sql-dacfx-162
